# Surface View Appears Black while the associated audio is playing in the background(android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player, android-gui

I am basically running a set of video tracks using a custom media player. Every thing works fine until I press home button or go to any other screen, then on after returning to the video play screen I can only hear the audio track as the videos play and screen appears black.

I would also like to highlight another issue for which i have got a stop gap arrangement, which is when i switch videos in the playlist, the surface view retains the last frame or image of the video that was previously played. I have tried to `invalidate()`, force the layout and all possible ways to refresh screen that i could think of, yet I couldn't find an appropriate solution for both of the issues mentioned.

Comment: Please post your code, especially the initialization of the media player and the playback resuming logic.